# Lua split with regular expression

Tags: regex, lua, split

I would like to make a split with lua to values separated with ','. For example:

```
  names="surname1 surname11, Name1,surname2, Name2,surname3, Name3, Name33"
```

and get:

```
 surname1 surname11, Name1
 surname2, Name2
 surname3, Name3, Name33
```

only when there isn't space or blanck on both sides of ',' should separate it.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Since the comma is being overloaded, change it to something else when it is a separator, as in the code below:

```
names=names:gsub("(%S),(%S)","%1|%2").."|"
for w in names:gmatch("(.-)|") do print(w) end
```

Comment: I prefer using `\0` as delimiter because it never collides with characters in C strings: `for w in names:gsub('(%S),(%S)','%1\0%2'):gmatch'%Z+' do`.  Unfortunately, handy `%Z` pattern will disappear from future Lua versions :-(

Comment: @Egor Really?! I didn't know that. That makes me a sad panda. Why remove it? D=

Comment: @greatwolf - [`%Z` is deprecated in Lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2) and should be rewritten as `[^\0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally never used lua but the regex youll need to find the comma with no space or blanks around it would be:

```
\w\,\w
```

I would just do a quick search on google at how to split a string in Lua.

Comment: Lua does not support regexes out-of-the-box, but it has patterns, with a slightly different syntax.